# CentOS Backup BASH Script

Tags: linux, centos, bash

I just wrote this script for backing up everything into a tar.gz file. Does it look okay? How can I get the tar file to transfer itself over to another server after executing? FTP from itself? I'm going to put this script into a weekly cron.

```
#!/bin/bash

rm ~/backup.tar.gz #removes old backup
BACKUP_DIRS=$HOME #$HOME is builtin, it goes to /home/ and all child dirs
tar -cvzf backup.tar.gz $BACKUP_DIRS

# run tar -zxvf to extract backup.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTP is the devil. SCP with RSA keypairs is a good way to move the files securely from server to server. As for the script, it looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response! THe script works, so I figured. Just wanted to make sure.

How hard is SCP? Is there a script for the transfer?

Comment: `man scp` isn't that difficult to read, is it :)

Comment: I am now. My question is, how do you handle the passwords between the two servers when sending the files? THanks.

Comment: RSA keypairs are passwordless.

Comment: On the sending server, create an ssh key pair using "ssh-keygen -t dsa".  Don't set a passphrase to encrypt the private key (by default, id_dsa).  Take the associated public key and put it on the receiving server, in the receiving user's authorized_keys file.  If the private key doesn't have a passphrase, it will not prompt you in a script.

Comment: Also take a look at the scponly or rssh for limited shell.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have many files that are changing, you might use rsync instead of making a big tar ball.  Rsync will only send changes, so it's much more network efficient than what you're proposing.  Maybe start by looking at something like this:

http://lifehacker.com/196122/geek-to-live--mirror-files-across-systems-with-rsync?tag=softwarersync

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the size of the server, you are creating an awful lot of duplicates. If I were you, I'd only back files that were modified. You should also datetime-stamp the file.

Here's what I would do.

- Do full back 1x per month or per week
- Incremental backups for all other days
- datetime-stamp the file for easier recovery

A real easy way to check the modified date of the file would be:

```
date -r $file +%F
```

so basically you can wrap that in a function and if the function doesn't match the date of the last backup, add it to the archive/backup. Otherwise move on.

HTH